# Understanding NativeScript GridLayout

Tags: nativescript

I am trying a simple test of the GridLayout and it is not working for me as expected.

Here is my view:

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
<GridLayout columns="80, *, auto" rows="80, 80, 80, *" >
    <Label row="0" col="0" text="r0col0" cssClass="green" />
    <Label row="0" col="1" text="r0col1" cssClass="green" />
    <Label row="0" col="2" text="r0col2" cssClass="green" />

    <Label row="1" col"0" text="r1col0" cssClass="blue" />
    <Label row="1" col"1" text="r1col1" cssClass="blue" />
    <Label row="1" col"2" text="r1col2" cssClass="blue" />

    <Label row="2" col="0" text="r2col0" cssClass="red" />
    <Label row="2" col="1" text="r2col1" cssClass="red" />
    <Label row="2" col="2" text="r2col2" cssClass="red" />
</GridLayout>
```

Here is my css:

```
label {
  font-size: 20;
  horizontal-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

When I run this in the iOS Emulator, I do not see row #1 (the blue row).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot about the equal (`=`) signs.

```xml
<Label row="1" col="0" text="r1col0" cssClass="blue" />
<Label row="1" col="1" text="r1col1" cssClass="blue" />
<Label row="1" col="2" text="r1col2" cssClass="blue" />
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can't believe i did that.

Comment: Anytime. We all miss things sometimes.